# Facebook Share Dialog - sharing a Facebook photo

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating a page tab on Facebook, everything is working as expected besides the sharing of photos within the page tab. YouTube links work perfectly.

What I would like to achieve is sharing of a photo previously uploaded to one of the page tabs photo albums. Basically replicating the action of clicking 'Share' when viewing a photo on Facebook.

As an example I am using Asda's photo.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=710406002364140'
});
```

This simply results in a dialog popping up momentarily with the loading animation.

Assuming this may be because Facebook prevents scraping of their own URLs as seen on the Open Graph Debugger

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

> Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger. Try your own.

Could anyone shed any light on ways around this?